# Connection to Seopolia/MainNet beacon

Tags: beacon, bitcoin-testnet

I am trying to connect nethermind to prysm consensus chain for interacting with lightnode in sepolia/main net

Based on this instruction i successfuly made first step
https://docs.nethermind.io/get-started/installing-nethermind

but during second step
https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/install/install-with-script

I bump into next issue
[1]    56039 killed     ./nethermind --config mainnet --JsonRpc.Enabled true --HealthChecks.Enabled
after this command on step 2.3
./nethermind --config mainnet --JsonRpc.Enabled true --HealthChecks.Enabled true --HealthChecks.UIEnabled true --JsonRpc.IpcUnixDomainSocketPath=Users/x/node/ethereum/execution

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Tried on MacOS

Tried to check process